# Creating a Kibana visualization based off of an ES REST API query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a query that I can run in Console of Kibana.  It returns all jobs that we run on some internal cluster grouped by job name, with aggregations showing the count of successes and errors for each job.  I can run this through Console like this:

```
GET /jobs-*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "kind": "job"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "jobs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "job.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "results": {
          "filters": {
            "other_bucket_key": "unsuccessful",
            "filters" : {
              "successful" :   { "match" : { "result" : "success"   }}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response looks something like this:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "jobs" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 28316,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 60708253,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "SomeJobName",
          "doc_count" : 38410,
          "results" : {
            "buckets" : {
              "successful" : {
                "doc_count" : 38206
              },
              "unsuccessful" : {
                "doc_count" : 204
              }
            }
          }
        },
        ...
}
```

I want to put this into some kind of Visualization (probably Data Table), that contains 3 columns: Job Name, Successful, Unsuccessful, and I want the table to display only the Top N of these by count of "Unsuccessful" column.

I'm pretty new to ES and Kibana, so it took me a while to even get this aggregation working, and now I can't figure out how to use this query to construct a Visualization, because it seems like the Visualization wants me to build up the query using some kind of GUI and restrictive KQL or Lucene syntax rather than just pasting in this request.

Is there something I'm overlooking?  How do I get a useful visualization out of these results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kibana only works the other way around -- you can build visualizations and then inspect the queries behind them. It wouldn't be feasible to paste a request and let the system "figure out" *what* you want to show and *how*. I wish it weren't.

But back to the original question -- KQL or Lucene syntax is not required when constructing a **query** -- you can use query DSL too!

[image]

[image]

But the aggregations do require KQL or Lucene...

As to the data table, this is the closest I could get:
[image]

---

When Kibana doesn't cut it, you'll need to create the charts/diagrams/tables yourselves. But before you do, check out [retool.com](https://retool.com/) (no affiliation). They let you [connect to ES](https://retool.com/integrations/elasticsearch), post-process the ES response, and create a data table of your liking in a super straightforward fashion. Would recommend.